# Is it feasible to convert an single MVC razor view/page into a SPA?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have an ASP.NET Core MVC application with multiple pages with one particular page having a lot of hand-made javascript code and ajax requests. It's becoming quite hard to manage and I would like to move to a framework like Angular, React etc for this particular page only. It is feasible to convert a single MVC view to a SPA app and still keep the other pages? Does anyone have any references on this? Google is not being too helpful...

Comment: Yes it's possible. Using a client-side framework like Angular and a server-side framework like ASP.NET Core are not mutually exclusive. As to how exactly to go about converting that action to client-side, that's far beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, and impossible to help you with, regardless, because there's no code here. In general, refer to the Angular documentation to set up your view, then most of your existing AJAX endpoints will likely end up being endpoints for the Angular code.

Comment: Thanks. I realise this is not the best medium for this question but appreciate you mentioning it is possible. I can now investigate it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I have found to do this is to use one of the SPA templates and then add the static pages around that.

Here's an an [example project](https://github.com/tura08/ASPNETCoreRazorPagesSpa) I have made that demonstrates the concept by adding a new Razor Page to the angular SPA template.

To do this for an already existing MVC/Razor Pages app I would suggest copying the following from an SPA template project to the MVC/Razor Pages app:

- ClientApp
- Controllers (SampleDataController.cs)
- Views (Home, Shared)
- npm_shrinkwrap.json
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- webpack.config.json
- webpack.config.vendor.json
- Startup.cs (copy the SPA things)

This is not an exhaustive list but should get someone most of the way.